How to implement server-side property validations?
I am trying to add custom validations for a component's properties in Umbraco, but I am not sure of what the best way of doing so is.
From what I've seen, everything points to having to set up a custom Property Editor. Is that the case?
Is there a way of hooking into existing properties and adding validations, without having to setup Property Editor types?

Have you tried the content service event? https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/notifications/contentservice-notifications. This will allow you to validate the field before saving.
